# Highcharts. Make tooltip of a specific point always visible

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, diagram

I need to make tooltip of some point make visible without moving mouse over the point. Say, I load my chart and have some tooltips already visible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Should it ALWAYS be visible? What should happen if you hover over another point?

Comment: It rather sounds like `dataLabels` option, not tooltip. Only one tooltip per chart is supported.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the tooltip to show automatically on a point on load:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(){
                // show tooltip on 4th point
                var p = this.series[0].points[3];
                this.tooltip.refresh(p);  
            }
        }
    },
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/489j7nxm/1/).

Comment: this is very clever

Answer (score 2):

Defaulty it is not available in the highcharts, but maybe better is using [flags](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement)

Comment: thanks, I'll check it. But so far I found datalabels.enabled : true

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood your terminology.